# No Button Splash Screen Animation Android

Tags: android, animation, button, screen, splash-screen

I want to rotate my animation, I know that after this lines I have to put a button:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.imgSplash));
final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate);
```

How can i start animation with no button?

Answer (score 0):

I just start my own app for android
but I don't quite understand what you mean by start a animation without a button.

does that mean you are able to side the animation only when the button is trigger?
are you looking for a triggered event trigger the animation?